# How to display the output of a script launched from another Ruby script in real time?

Tags: ruby, output, command-line-interface

I wrote a Ruby script that, at some point in its execution, will run `bundle install` to install gems from a Gemfile. This is the relevant part:

```
puts "installing gems ..."
puts `bundle install --without production`
puts "gems installed."
```

What happens here is that although the `bundle install` command is properly executed, I only see the output in the CLI once all the gems have been installed. Meaning I first get `installing gems ...` and then it waits and I get all the output lines of `bundle install` plus the `gems installed` message together.

Is there a way to display the output of `bundle install` line by line in real time as it gets executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`Kernel#system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) instead of the backticks:

```
system "bundle install --without production"
```

Comment: Awesome! It does exactly what I need. I was sure backticks and `system` were aliases but obviously, I was completely wrong. Thank you.